# #1109 - Unknown table 'QUESTION_ANSWER' in MULTI DELETE

Tags: mysql, join, sql-delete, delete-row

I am learning MySQL, and learning multi-delete but can not get it fully.

I have 4 tables.

1. USERS
2. QUESTION
3. ANSWER
4. QUESTION_ANSWER

I want to query that when it deletes a user, it deletes all related data in QUESTION, ANSWER, QUESTION_ANSWER.

My table structure is as follows

```
TABLE: ANSWER

ANSWER_NUMBER (PRIMARY KEY)
VOTE_COUNT
isAccepted
ANSWER_DESCRIPTION
USER_ID (FOREIGN KEY FROM USERS.USER_ID)

TABLE: QUESTION

QUESTION_NUMBER (PRIMARY KEY)
QUESTION_DESCRIPTION
VOTE_COUNT
QUESTION_VIEWS
USER_ID
QUESTION_NUMBER_OF_ANSWERS

Table: QUESTION_ANSWER

Q_NUM (FOREIGN KEY FROM QUESTION.QUESTION_NUMBER)
A_NUM (FOREIGN KEY FROM ANSWER.ANSWER_NUMBER)

TABLE USERS:

USER_ID (PRIMARY)
USER_NAME
USER_REPUTATION
USER_NO_OF_ANSWERS
USER_NO_OF_QUESTIONS
```

Let say I want to delete user id 1; I want to remove all questions, answers by user id 1.

I have reached here sofar.

```sql
DELETE QUESTION_ANSWER, QUESTION, USERS, ANSWER 
FROM USERS
    INNER JOIN
    QUESTION ON QUESTION_ANSWER.Q_NUM = QUESTION.QUESTION_NUMBER
    INNER JOIN ANSWER
    ON ANSWER.ANSWER_NUMBER = QUESTION_ANSWER.A_NUM
    WHERE USERS.USER_ID=1;
```

But it giving error

```
DELETE QUESTION_ANSWER, QUESTION, USERS, ANSWER 
FROM USERS
    INNER JOIN
    QUESTION ON QUESTION_ANSWER.Q_NUM = QUESTION.QUESTION_NUMBER
    INNER JOIN ANSWER
    ON ANSWER.ANSWER_NUMBER = QUESTION_ANSWER.A_NUM
    WHERE USERS.USER_ID=1
MySQL said: Documentation

#1109 - Unknown table 'QUESTION_ANSWER' in MULTI DELETE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, add cascade in foreign keys where ever you want to delete when any of related record is deleted, For example, one user can create many questions so it's mean the foreign key is in Questions table so apply to cascade over there means whenever a user is deleted it's related questions would also be deleted.

```
CREATE TABLE USERS(
    USER_ID  INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    USER_NAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    USER_REPUTATION INT NOT NULL,
    USER_NO_OF_ANSWERS INT NOT NULL,
    USER_NO_OF_QUESTIONS INT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE QUESTION(
    QUESTION_NUMBER INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    QUESTION_DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    VOTE_COUNT INT NOT NULL,
    QUESTION_VIEWS INT NOT NULL,
    USER_ID INT NOT NULL,
    QUESTION_NUMBER_OF_ANSWERS INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY QUESTION(USER_ID) REFERENCES USERS(USER_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Now insert some data in both tables and try to delete 1 user to clearly understand the concept of cascading, you will see that just by deleting the user, questions related to that user will also delete automatically. The delete query is:

```
DELETE FROM USERS [WHERE Clause]
```

Now you will be clear about the concept, the second step is, try to add a foreign key in the ANSWER table and also apply cascading over there because Answers are also relevant to Users (clearly shown in your question that you want to delete answers of a particular user).

```
CREATE TABLE ANSWER(
    ANSWER_NUMBER INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    VOTE_COUNT INT,
    isAccepted INT,
    ANSWER_DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    USER_ID INT NOT NULL,
    FOREING KEY ANSWER(USER_ID) REFERENCES USERS(USER_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Now the last thing is to also delete the records from the bridge table QUESTION_ANSWER.

```
CREATE TABLE QUESTION_ANSWER(
    Q_NUM  INT NOT NULL,
    A_NUM  INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY QUESTION_ANSWER(Q_NUM) REFERENCES QUESTION(QUESTION_NUMBER) ON 
    DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY QUESTION_ANSWER(A_NUM) REFERENCES ANSWER(ANSWER_NUMBER) ON 
    DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Now you are good to go, just delete any record of user it's related records in QUESTIONS, ANSWERS & QUESTION_ANSWER table will also be deleted.

```
DELETE FROM USERS [WHERE Clause]
```

Answer (score 2):

The tables participating in the joins must be all defined **after** the `FROM` clause.
In the `DELETE` clause you must enumerate the tables from which the rows will be deleted.

```
DELETE qa, q, u, a 
FROM USERS u
INNER JOIN QUESTION q ON q.USER_ID = u.USER_ID
INNER JOIN QUESTION_ANSWER qa ON qa.Q_NUM = q.QUESTION_NUMBER
INNER JOIN ANSWER a ON a.ANSWER_NUMBER = qa.A_NUM
WHERE u.USER_ID=1
```

As you can see, I used aliases for the tables, so that the code is shorter and more readable.

If you have defined referential integrity between the tables with `ON DELETE CASCADE`, something like:

```
CREATE TABLE USERS(
USER_ID  int PRIMARY KEY,
USER_NAME VARCHAR(100),
USER_REPUTATION int,
USER_NO_OF_ANSWERS int,
USER_NO_OF_QUESTIONS int
);

CREATE TABLE ANSWER(
ANSWER_NUMBER int PRIMARY KEY,
VOTE_COUNT int,
isAccepted int,
ANSWER_DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE TABLE QUESTION(
QUESTION_NUMBER  int PRIMARY KEY,
QUESTION_DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(100),
VOTE_COUNT int,
QUESTION_VIEWS int,
USER_ID int,
QUESTION_NUMBER_OF_ANSWERS int,
FOREIGN KEY(USER_ID) REFERENCES USERS(USER_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE QUESTION_ANSWER(
Q_NUM  int,
A_NUM  int,
FOREIGN KEY(Q_NUM) REFERENCES QUESTION(QUESTION_NUMBER) ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY(A_NUM) REFERENCES ANSWER(ANSWER_NUMBER) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

then all you have to do is delete the row from `USERS` and `ANSWER` and all the rows of the child tables will be deleted also:

```
DELETE u, a 
FROM USERS u
INNER JOIN QUESTION q ON q.USER_ID = u.USER_ID
INNER JOIN QUESTION_ANSWER qa ON qa.Q_NUM = q.QUESTION_NUMBER
INNER JOIN ANSWER a ON a.ANSWER_NUMBER = qa.A_NUM
WHERE u.USER_ID=1
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5b6b29612030821dc0916eadb1895343).

Comment: It is giving ```#1451 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`STACKOVERFLOW`.`ANSWER`, CONSTRAINT `ANSWER_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`USER_ID`) REFERENCES `USERS` (`USER_ID`))``` error when `USER_ID=5`, otherwise query is running but not deleting anything.

Comment: You must respect the order of deleting begin by childs tables and end by parents.